# Datagrid: generate columns from a property of the ItemsSource collection

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to create a datagrid with auto generating columns.
Let's say my Collection is a property named `Articles` of my viewmodel of type `ObservableCollection<ArticleWrapper>`.

I bind now the ItemsSource to this collection:

```
<wpf:DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Articles} />
```

The class `ArticleWrapper` is like this:

```
[c#]
public class ArticleWrapper
{
    public ArticleConfigurationSet ArticleConfigurationSet { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


[vb.net]
Public Class ArticleWrapper
    Public Property ArticleConfigurationSet As ArticleConfigurationSet
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

The class `ArticleConfigurationSet` is like this:

```
[c#]
public class ArticleConfigurationSet
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}

[vb.net]
Public Class ArticleConfigurationSet
    Public Property Key As String
    Public Property Number As Integer
End Class
```

The autogenerated columns look like this (please forget about the CustomEntries):
[image]

But now my problem: I want to bind the displayed data to my `ArticleConfigurationSet` property. But I cannot change my ItemsSource Binding, because the SelectedItem property of the datagrid must be of `ArticleWrapper` (for command handling).

The datagrid should also look like this:
[image]

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: i'll generate a more view friendly viewmodel with linq and do it on the old way.. but thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not set AutoGenrateColumns = false and create the gridcolumns and bindings dynamic in dependence of your ArticleConfigurationSet properties?

you dont have to change the view and you can do what you want.

edit: i mean you can iterate through your ArticleConfigurationSet properties(e.g. with reflection) and create the Gridcolumns and bindings by you.

```
 foreach(var p in properties)
 {
      //grid add new gridcolumn
      //set binding to ArticleConfigurationSet Property Name
      var b = new Binding("ArticleConfigurationSet"+p.Name);
      //add binding to gridcolumn
 }
```

Comment: That's not my problem. The displayed columns should auto generate from my object. And I don't want to do this fixed by xaml, because in further versions the object can (and will) change.

Comment: thats the problem the object you want to autogenrate your grid from is not the object you bind to. so you have to do something by your self.

Answer (score 3):

You can have both `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, and define your own custom Columns

For example,

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridColumn Binding="{Binding ArticleConfigurationSet.Key}" Header="Key" />
        <DataGridColumn Binding="{Binding ArticleConfigurationSet.Value}" Header="Value" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

// If we are auto-generating the ArticleConfigurationSet column, 
// cancel it so that column doesn't get rendered
void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.ColumnName == "ArticleConfigurationSet")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

You might have to do some code-behind if you want to rearrange your column order, however this should auto-generate columns for everything in your object except your `ArticleConfigurationSet` column, and it will also add two other columns for the `ArticleConfigurationSet.Key` and `ArticleConfigurationSet.Value`

Comment: he just wants columns for the ArticleConfigurationSet and no other - or?

Comment: @blindmeis It sounds like he is looking for a way to auto-generate all columns, except the `ArticleConfigurationSet` column which he wants to show up as two specific columns that show `Key` and `Value`. This solution does that.

Answer (score 1):

Set **AutoGenrateColumns = false** and use **ItemTemplate** having a **Lable** and bind it to the field or property you want.

Comment: That would work, but i want to autogenerate all the columns, so if there comes new properties I don't need to change the view.